# Can it be assumed that number of partitions in a spark dataframe persists after being written to a table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I recently inherited a Scala project that uses Spark. The CI pipeline succeeded the last time it ran but that was over six months ago, since then our CI infrastructure has changed and I am now changing this CI pipeline to run on the new infrastructure (basically used to run on an on-premises kubernetes cluster, it now has to run on a cloud-based kubernetes cluster).

A test that used to succeed is now failing and the only thing that has changed is the infrastructure on which it runs. The problematic code in questions boils down to this:

```scala
val tableName = "data_table_3_spark_partitions"
spark.createDataFrame(someData).repartition(3).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable(tableName)
val numberOfSparkPartitionsPriorToErase = spark.table(tableName).rdd.getNumPartitions
numberOfSparkPartitionsPriorToErase shouldBe 3
```

The test now fails on that 4th line with:

> 1 was not equal to 3

The dataframe being written contains only 5 rows (it *is* a unit test after all)

The code is running against a local filesystem, here is the SparkConf:

```scala
new SparkConf().
      setMaster("local[*]").
      setAppName("test").
      set("spark.ui.enabled", "false").
      set("spark.app.id", appID).
      set("spark.driver.host", "localhost").
      set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")
```

---

It seems to me that this is a somewhat brittle test because it is predicated on the following assumption:

> *when a spark dataframe is written to a table and then that table read into a new dataframe, the new dataframe will have the same number of partitions as the original dataframe*

I think this failing test proves that that is a false assumption. Am I correct that that is a false assumption?

Comment: I think the assumption is not entirely correct. The number of partitions after read may be affected by `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html.

Comment: ok, so the assumption *is* correct then :) i.e. the assumption is that we shouldn't assume they'll be the same (sorry, I should have written the question so it wasn't implying a double negative)

Comment: :)) `...repartition(3).write...` will create at least three files in file system (if table is not partitioned). During subsequent read, these three files could be read into a single Spark partition if their combined size is under `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes`.

Comment: thanks, that helps enormously. Given there are only 5 rows in the table (and only 3 columns in each row) the total size would easily fall under the default `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` of 128MB. The only mystery is why this test succeeded previously but now fails.

Comment: Maybe storage format for the table has changed?

Comment: I don't see how it could. The only thing that has changed is the underlying infrastructure, the code itself has not. Everything is being written as parquet.

Comment: Is the global spark and yarn configuration on this cloud cluster the same as it was on your on-premise cluster?

Comment: Its not using yarn. These unit tests are running in a small container running atop a kubernetes cluster. I have updated the question to show the SparkConf of the SparkSession.

Comment: to me it seems people worry too much about all this stuff

Comment: I don't think so. I think it is an interesting question to pursue but may not be at the top of the priorities order.

Comment: Do you use hdfs in both cases?

Comment: it does use hdfs insofar as once the data is written I can read the files `spark.sessionState.catalog.listPartitions(org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.TableIdentifier(tableName))).map(_.location).map(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(_)).map(path => org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.Configuration(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)).listStatus(path))` however that location is actually the local filesystem, there's an hdfs shim over that filesystem. So the answer is "yes, Spark thinks it talking to hdfs but in reality it is not".Hope that makes sense